# zaproxy: unable to find image 'in:latest' locally

Tags: docker, zap

I followed example from : https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2017/06/scanning-apis-with-zap.html

1. install Docker on my Mac
2. executed `docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly`
3. executed example: `docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t \
       https://www.example.com/openapi.json -f openapi` 
   it works
4. executed my command to scan my API : `docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t myapitest.json -f openapi`
   And I got: 
   *Unable to find image 'in:latest' locally
   docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for in, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.*
   I googled to find the solution, as I'm novice both in Docker and ZAP, but in vain.

Comment: look like docker issue, try running only `docker run -it owasp/zap2docker-weekly` to make sure it is working. From some reason, docker does not catch the image name

Comment: @OmerLeviHevroni , I've run and got: zap@87049f10f43c:/zap$

Answer (score 8):

Your current working directory likely has spaces in its path. Because of this, `-v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw` is seen as two arguments, and the second one is seen as name of the image to run.

For example:

```
# create a directory having spaces, last part is "baz"
mkdir foo\ bar\ baz

# change to that directory
cd foo\ bar\ baz

# attempt to run a container that bind-mounts the current
# directory, and see that it's producing an error:
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/foo busybox

Unable to find image 'bar:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bar, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

What's happening, is that `$(foo)` is expanded to its full path:

```
pwd
/Users/sebastiaan/Projects/spaces/foo bar baz
```

So, running the docker command actually runs:

```
docker run --rm -v  /Users/sebastiaan/Projects/spaces/foo bar baz:/foo busybox
```

And docker sees `bar` as the name of the image you're trying to run

To work around this, put quotes around `$(pwd)`;

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/foo busybox
```